# SQL brings more than one row of the same data

Tags: sql-server

I tried researching before asking, but couldn't find anything or maybe I used the wrong keywords. I might get a -1 for that, but anyway.
In the exercise I'm doing I need to select the following expression
salary + comission value + trip expenses - discounts.
This is my select:

```
select a.id_vendor, a.name_vendor, a.id_region, a.salary + b.value + c.value - d.value
from vendors a 
inner join comission b
on a.id_vendor = b.id_vendor
inner join trip_expenses c
on a.id_vendor = c.id_vendor
inner join discounts d
on a.id_vendor = d.id_vendor
group by a.id_vendor, a.name_vendor, a.id_region, a.salary, b.value, c.value, d.value;
```

I've tried adding sum to some of the number records, but didn't work.
The thing is, that when I execute this select it brings more than one record for the same Vendor ID, and I would like that they be summed into just one column.
This is the result:

```
id_vendor   name_vendor                    id_region   
----------- ------------------------------ ----------- ---------------------------------------
1           Marco                          1           1955.00
1           Marco                          1           2180.00
2           Walesca                        2           3190.00
3           Carol                          3           4970.00
4           Evelyn                         4           1860.00
5           Wallace                        5           10130.00
```

As you can see, Marco comes twice because he has more than one record on the discounts table.

How do correct that? What's wrong with my select?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: He has more than one record on the discounts table.  Now, if you only want one discount record per vendor, which discount should be chosen?  Huh?  TELL ME NOW.  WHICH ONE???  Obviously, id_vendor should have a unique index in the discounts table if you aren't doing a one-to-many relationship.  So do that.  And break everything else.  Then fix what broke.  Welcome to programming.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the structure of your discounts table, it is hard to provide a definitive answer.

That said, and assuming that you have date ranges or some other indicator of when the discount should be applied, add that to your query in a where clause.

```
select a.id_vendor, a.name_vendor, a.id_region, a.salary + b.value + c.value - d.value
from vendors a 
inner join comission b
on a.id_vendor = b.id_vendor
inner join trip_expenses c
on a.id_vendor = c.id_vendor
inner join discounts d
on a.id_vendor = d.id_vendor
-- Add a where clause looking at Start/End Dates
where d.StartDate < GetDate() and getdate() < d.EndDate
group by a.id_vendor, a.name_vendor, a.id_region, a.salary, b.value, c.value, d.value;
```

Hopefully this helps. If not, you may have to post your schema for your tables so we have a better idea of what you are working with.

Comment: My discounts table is very simple, it only contains the id of the vendor, and the value of its discount. It's just a homework so nothing is very much detailed and well planned.

Comment: About posting my schema It'd be hard because I'm brazilian and I would need to translate it whole.

Comment: Why do you have 2 records in the discounts table for the same vendor? I think that is your root cause.

Comment: I should have a  date field (as you showed) or something else to be able to filter... I feel embarassed haha, thanks Martin.